# How to select rows filtered by more than one entry in map colum (Cassandra 3.9)

Tags: cassandra, query-optimization, data-modeling

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test.products (
id uuid PRIMARY KEY,
name text,
params map<text, text>);
```

I've created an entry index on params field like this:

```
CREATE INDEX products_params_idx ON test.products (entries(params));
```

Let's say i have 3 products in that table with such params values:

```
1. {'param1' : 'value1', 'param2' : 'value2'}
2. {'param1' : 'value1', 'param2' : 'othervalue'}
3. {'param3' : 'value3', 'param2' : 'value2'}
```

Each product can have only one value per one param, but in whole database there can be N params and X values for each of them.

I can do a query like that with no problems:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE params['param1'] = 'value1';
```

**But the main question is how can I do a query like this:**

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE params['param1'] = 'value1' AND params['param2'] = 'value2';
```

Now i get an error, which warns me about efficiency:

```
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering and thus may have unpredictable performance. If you want to execute this query despite the performance unpredictability, use ALLOW FILTERING"
```

I am preety new to Cassandra and NoSQL. I know from Datastax courses, that using `ALLOW FILTERING` is the last thing i should do in Cassandra. Is there an efficient way to achieve what i want in Cassandra? Maybe I should model this in a whole different way? I will be very glad for some help in this topic.

Comment: yes you r right for changing you model as you cannot create table with param(column of map type ) as primary key nor as materialsed view (Collection types cannot be part of the primary key, and neither can the counter type. ) . so if you want to skip the "ALLOW FILTERING" you need to included the primary key in query .

Comment: Collections are small groups of data that you fetch all at once.

If you want to access tuples at a finer level, and still be able to ask "what are all the pairs of data for a given key," you should use a table like this:

CREATE TABLE details (
  key TEXT,
  detail_key text,
  detail_value text,
  PRIMARY KEY (key, detail_key)
);

This will allow SELECT * FROM details WHERE key = ? as well as SELECT * FROM detail WHERE key = ? AND detail_key = ?.

Answer (score 1):

If you want select data based on product attributes and value, model the primary key based on param and value columns, create additional table for such requirement.

```
    create table name_by_param{
    param text,
    value text,
    uuid text,
    name text
    primary key ((param,value),uuid)
    }
```

Example inserts for product - Darthvedar

```
    insert into name_by_param (param,value,uuid,name) values ('birthname','ani','uuid1','darthvedar');
    insert into name_by_param (param,value,uuid,name) values ('side','darkside','uuid1','darthvedar');
    insert into name_by_param (param,value,uuid,name) values ('age','40','uuid1','darthvedar');
```

example inserts for product - Obi-wan-kenobi

```
insert into name_by_param (param,value,uuid,name) values ('birthname','O-ben','uuid2','Obi-wan-kenobi');
insert into name_by_param (param,value,uuid,name) values ('side','force','uuid2','Obi-wan-kenobi');
insert into name_by_param (param,value,uuid,name) values ('age','40','uuid2','Obi-wan-kenobi');
```

Select queries --

```
select * from name_by_param where token(param,value) = token('birthname','ani') and token(param,value) =  token('side','force');
```

Above query should return two rows, I haven't tried it myself, but it shoud work, hope this will help.

Comment: I really liked the idea, but it seems that it can't be used with equality operator:`param, value cannot be restricted by more than one relation if it includes an Equal` - i it works if I change it to gt or lt, but that obviously didn't solve the problem then.

Comment: Did you tried "OR" in thet query, for example  -token(param,value) = token('birthname','ani') { OR  } token(param,value) =  token('side','force');

Comment: Also you an try  IN operator example - token(..) IN (token(...),token(...))

Comment: Sry, no OR equivalent in Cassandra afaik, but i tried to be sure and get syntax error. When using "in" `select * from name_by_param where token(param,value) IN (token('birthname','ani'), token('side','force'));` i get an error too, but slightly different: `no viable alternative at input 'IN' (... where token(param,value) [IN]...)` - maybe it's just some stupid sytnax mistake, but i can't figure that out.

Comment: After the docs (http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/dml.html#select)  - `Moreover, the IN relation is only allowed on the last column of the partition key and on the last column of the full primary key.` :/

Comment: In 2.2 you can use the IN operator on any partition key column. -- From same document